# Scala + Akka, pass byte arrays of images via messages?

Tags: scala, akka, message-passing

I am creating a web service that receives an image from the client (I work with it as an array of bytes). I would like to create an actor that create thumbnails of different sizes. Is it a good idea to have the actor send back a message that contains multiple images like this?

```
class ImagesMessage(thumb1: Array[Byte], thumb2: Array[Byte], thumb3: Array[Byte])
```

What I am really wondering is: should I send potentially large files or should I better do other tricks like storing it somewhere and pass the link back?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading between the lines, you are only worried about performance? If so, don't, you are already passing a reference. Nevertheless, I would use an immutable data structure to prevent destructive changes to the original data in case you're sending it to other actors.

Comment: What if the receiving actor is a remote actor? I guess at that point we're not talking reference anymore?

Comment: Exactly you shouldn't assume you're passing a reference if you ever want to scale out. Are you able to place a limit on what size of image the user can upload? If so what kind of max would be feasible?

Comment: @ticofab I don't think you should be doing anything special around performance at the moment. Akka deals with the serialization - go with it. Of course, if you passing a tonne of data around, you may want to think about alternatives. From the context I got from your message, you're passing thumbnails, and that IMO will scale out just fine.